# Mean-field in Bose-Einstein condensate

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, mean-field-theory

Why we use a mean-field theory in Bose-Eisntein condensate?  Is there another formulation that does not use a mean-field theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mean-field theory is a good ansatz for a number of simple cases. Neglecting all interactions and assuming full "connectedness" of all particles, the Hartree-Fock separation into a product state and assuming a pseudo-potential should be exact. When it is not exact, the ansatz leads to a non-linear Schrödinger equation where the higher powers are perturbative corrections, i.e. a Gross-Pitaevskii equation. There are other ways to do perturbation theory of course.

There are many other ways to treat a condensate wavefunction. These methods can be better because they take condesate geometry, size and time evolution into account as well as interactions within the condensate and with non-condensed atoms. These methods either rely on some other perturbation theory or stochastic methods, to my knowledge. This paper gives a brief introduction: https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3541

See also [Gross-Pitaevskii equation in Bose-Einstein condensates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46652/gross-pitaevskii-equation-in-bose-einstein-condensates?rq=1)